# how to get a videos from amazon s3 account into my joomla site

Tags: joomla, amazon-s3, jwplayer

i have used jw player in my joomla site. i need to get a videos from amazon s3 into my joomla site??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
< object classid=”clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000″ codebase=”http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,19,0″ width=”720” height=”380“  title=”My video”>
<param name=”movie” value=”http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/s3browser/myvideo.mov” />
<param name=”quality” value=”high” />
<embed src=”http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/s3browser/myvideo.mov” quality=”high” pluginspage=”http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer” type=”application/x-shockwave-flash” width=”720” height=”380“></embed>
</object>
```

replace the **src** with your videos URL

Comment: frd thks 4 ur help..!!! pls explain deeply ..!! where can i use this codes...!!!

Comment: just go to the article manager and create new article and insert new code or add to pre created articles ..are you clear now ? :-)

Comment: thnks frd..!! but i need to create video gallery frm amazon..pls see my site

Comment: http://websolusionz.com/ourprojects/yogamother/

Comment: http://goo.gl/PcidT use this extension it will help !